# Получить данные из атрибута. React, Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Какие есть варианты получения данных из атрибута HTML тега?
Знаю, что есть вариант получения через event.currentTarget.getAttribute(""). Но мне интересно какие ещё есть способы, кроме ивента, потому что у меня возникают некоторые сложности при использовании данного способа.

Обрисую ситуацию: есть классовый компонент, в componentDidMount приходит массив и в рендере отрисовывается в список. У каждого объекта в массиве есть своё поле id. Вот это id я записал в key каждого элемента списка. Есть ли какой-то способ прочитать данные из этого атрибута? Если нет, то может как-то ещё можно получить id конкретного элемента списка?

Answer (score 0):

Передайте в дочерний компонент проп `id` и используйте как вам вздумается. Атрибут key используется react`ом для других целей.

```js
const Parent = () => { //родитель, который создает потомков с ID
  return (
   <Child elementId={'someId'}/>
  )
}


const Child = ({elementId}) => { //потомок, который получает ID
  return (
  <div 
    onClick={(event)=>console.log(elementId)}
  >
    {elementId}
   </div>
  )
}
```